# Vue binding overrides element attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that renders a HTML input:

```
<input
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    v-model="value"
    type="text"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :readOnly="readOnly"
    @focus="onFocus"
/>
```

Note that the `type` is not binded/reactive.

When I put this component inside another, and bind a object to it, the `type` gets overrided.

```
 <my-input v-bind="{type: 'foobar'}"></my-input>
```

---

**Is this a `by design` or a `bug`?**

---

Example (check the `input[type]` in the HTML):

```js
const Input = {
    template: '<input type="text"/>'
    //                      ^^^^ "text" gets overriden to "foobar"
}
new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    components: {
        'my-input': Input
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <my-input v-bind="{type: 'foobar'}"></my-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered this in an issue, this is expected

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5846#issuecomment-307098682

You can, however, disregard attrs by adding them as props and ignore them

```
const Input = {
    props: ['type'],
    template: '<input type="text"/>'
    //                      ^^^^ "text" won't get overriden
}
new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    components: {
        'my-input': Input
    }
});
```

Other attributes like `class` get merged but `type` can only be overriden

Comment: I think you meant to get rid of the comment? "text" does not get overwritten

Comment: Yes, I forgot, to edit the comment. It's now fixed :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

VueJS adds the component attributes to the first child node of the component template.

Look this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8hzhvrng/

The `my-input` has a `input`root child and then it gets the `type="password"`

The my-input2 has a `div` root child which gets the `type="number"`